# VBA Macro Vlookup and Index Match function for dynamic number of sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I use a macro to run index match and vlookup functions by recording them manually. The problem is that the sheet target is not always available, sometimes only 3 or 5 sheets only so its totally random

here's the code that I use

```
Sub Function()

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'COA
Sheets(2).Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Status
Sheets(2).Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'ACF'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'ACF'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BOD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'BOD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'GDG'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'GDG'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HC3'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HC3'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'IT'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'IT'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'LDD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'LDD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MCD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MCD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MSD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'MSD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'NPD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'NPD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'TSD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),VLOOKUP(RC3,'TSD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0)" & _
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

end sub
```

is there any way to make the formula run only available sheets on the workbook? because if I run it as is, it always asks to update the formula for the sheet that isn't available on the workbook.

Comment: The formula is just a string, so you can build it according to the sheets present in the workbook, then apply it to the cell.  Or you might consider making a UDF to repalce the use of the formula.

Comment: @TimWilliams the sheet on my present workbook is not always the same number, sometimes 3 or 5 or so on. I try to lookup to internet that I need to use `worksheet.count` but still no clue how to do that. Could you give me the example of the formula? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the sheets in your workbook.

```vb
Sub insertCOAandStatusFormulas()

'Pattern of each formula part - $1 as placeholder for sheetname

Dim strPartCOA As String, strPartStatus As String
strPartCOA = "IFERROR(INDEX('$1'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'$1'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('$1'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'$1'!R6C5:R2000C5,0)), "
strPartStatus = "IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'$1'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'$1'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0), "


Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")    '--> adjust this to your needs


'build sheet-specific part per formula
Dim strFormulaCOA As String, strFormulaStatus As String
Dim cntSheets As Long, i As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> wsTarget.Name Then
        strFormulaCOA = strFormulaCOA & Replace(strPartCOA, "$1", ws.Name) & vbCrLf
        strFormulaStatus = strFormulaStatus & Replace(strPartStatus, "$1", ws.Name) & vbCrLf
        cntSheets = cntSheets + 1
    End If
Next

'add equal-sign, remove last comma and add closing brackets
If LenB(strFormulaCOA) > 0 Then

    'XXXX this part is not working XXXX - you would have to find out, how many brackets you have to add and at which position they have to go
    strFormulaCOA = "=" & Left(strFormulaCOA, Len(strFormulaCOA) - 4) & ", ""no value found""" & String((cntSheets * 2), ")")
    strFormulaStatus = "=" & Left(strFormulaStatus, Len(strFormulaStatus) - 4) & ", ""no value found""" & String((cntSheets + 2) + 1, ")")
    
    With wsTarget
        .Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = strFormulaCOA
        .Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = strFormulaStatus
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

You have to make adjustments regarding the brackets - see comment in code

Comment: If I want to add more place within the sheet, same formula but just different lookup column for index match and the vlookup, I need to add more formula and the wsTarget, is that correct? or should I add other line?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "add more place"?

Comment: what I mean is the cell right side of the formula containing the COA is the same but just with different cell (COA column A, Div column B) and the right side cell containing the status formula (E6 until S6) also have the same formula but different column to lookup, for example if status on D6 is looking up column 4 or 2 then E6 look up column 5 or 3 and so on.

Comment: Well - you could put another placeholder for the offsets in strPartCOA  - and replace accordingly.

Comment: I see, so I just need add the different formulas for different cells with the same structure of code

Comment: I got error on this line `Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws Is Not wsTarget Then
        strPartCOA = strFormulaCOA & Replace(strPartCOA, "$1", ws.Name) & vbCrLf
        strPartStatus = strFormulaStatus & Replace(strPartStatus, "$1", ws.Name) & vbCrLf
        cntSheets = cntSheets + 1
    End If`
on the `If ws Is Not wsTarget Then` line with error code 438

any idea for the correction?

Comment: You could try `If ws.name <> wstarget.name Then`

Comment: sorry for the late response, I try to change with `if ws.name <> wstarget.name` still get the same error

Comment: I just resolve the issue but now the issue go to line `strFormulaCOA = "=" & Left(strFormulaCOA, Len(strFormulaCOA) - 2) & String(cntSheets, ")")` with runtime error 5 invalid procedure call or argument
Any idea for it?

Comment: Ok - I updated the code - but in the end I wasn't able to build a working formula - I think the number and position of the brackets is not correct. Sorry - no more time to investigte. But in the end you should propably rethink the whole process - formulas like that are very error prone ...

Comment: just try the updated code, no error was found but nothing happen when I try to run the code. The formula like the upper one, what should I do to make the formula better?